# Saving .mdb on a commonFile in a shared drive for multi user connection

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, forms

I want to build a VB.NET form that users can interact with by entering data. I want the data to be accessible to everyone in my organization.

If I save the .mdb file in a shared drive and folder, would everyone with access to that drive be able to access data from my .mdb?

Comment: A better option, if it is available to you, is to have SQL Server running on a machine available to all the computers in the organization. SQL Server is meant to be used by multiple users - .mdb files are not. (Or you could use any of many available multi-user databases such as MySQL or [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/).)

Comment: I don't have SQL server running on the machine,

Comment: Why wouldnt the .mdb file be accessible by other users? if no login is required?

Comment: Microsoft Access is not intended for multiple users. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Do you want to be the person who has to explain to management that you chose a flaky solution over something that works, when the difference in cost is zero?

Comment: you have a point.     thank you

Comment: @AndrewMorton _"Microsoft Access is not intended for multiple users"_ - **yes it is** - it's a specifically supported scenario, e.g.: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ways-to-share-an-access-desktop-database-03822632-da43-4d8f-ba2a-68da245a0446 : "the database file is stored on a shared network drive, and all users share the database file simultaneously" - while I'll agree it isn't ideal, the JET/ACE engine handles concurrent locking scenarios over SMB just fine.